# How do I set the Safari's homepage?

Tags: macos, safari

How do I set the homepage of my Safari 8.0.7 or, even better, customize it?

Comment: On the Safari menu click Help > Search > type homepage and select Set your Safari homepage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. On the keyboard, press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> (command-comma) or go to Safari → Preferences...

   [image]
2. Choose the General tab and set a home page in the Homepage field.

   [image]

Comment: Can't find that button... help??

Comment: Preference button......

Comment: @Estella I've added screenshots.

Comment: Where??????????

Comment: You also have to set "new tabs open with" to "home page", otherwise it will still load the top sites.